# Android Handler Looper Dark Theme behavior

Tags: android, android-theme, android-handler, kotlin-android-extensions

I experienced interesting behavior with Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()). It gets executed twice if my app theme (day/night) is set to different from OS Settings. For example if Dark mode is turned off in device settings and my app MainActivity applies dark theme, then MainActivity starts twice. I did`t find any explanation on why it happens.

**SplashActivity very simple**

```
class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen_layout)

        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            Log.i("SPLASH","Main activity started")
            finish()
        }, 2000)
    }

}
```

Main Activity has the following function to check what theme is saved in app settings and apply it:

**Function**

```
private fun checkDarkMode(){
        when (MainSettings(this).darkMode) {
            0 -> {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM)
                delegate.applyDayNight()
            }
            1 -> {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
                delegate.applyDayNight()
            }
            2 -> {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
                delegate.applyDayNight()
            }
        }
    }
```

So here if dark mode is turned off in device settings, then handler code will be executed twice for AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES, for others just once as intended.

It also happens vise versa, if device dark on, then code executes twice for AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO.

As I said I didn`t find any explanation or solution, so what I did is just defined handler as val and cancelled everything for it in onPause or onDestroy of SplashActivity

```
private val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
    }
```

So my question is why it happens and is there another way to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look at the source for `AppCompatDelegate` which is [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/refs/heads/master/sdk/sources/android-25/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java) (take a lot around line 201 for the part where it recreates the activity).

I can't offer a direct solution to your problem but an alternative would be to just inherit from one of the `DayNight` themes (although you do lose the ability to have a night theme on anything below Android 10, but in my opinion it makes things a lot easier).

Edit: You might be able to perform your `checkDarkMode` method in an `Application` class, this should hopefully set the correct mode before any activites are created (thus avoiding them being created again when it changes).

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    checkDarkMode()
}
```

Comment: I knew that it recreates activity, but apparently besides MainActivity, SplashScreen gets recreated as well. I also call AppDelegate in my Settings Fragment and it only recreates MainActivity. Changing theme in Application Class actually looks much smoother than in Activity, almost unnoticeable. So I am gonna stick with it. Thanks for the tip ;)